# Ebizmarts Mage Monkey Magento Extention Mandrill Api Key Not Working on Localhost

Tags: magento

I am working with magento transactional email. I want to use mandrill for transactional email sending to customer. When i work with the Api key with live site then work but same Api key Not Working on Localhost.
Is There any solution to cover this problem.

Here is the Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please post here last ~20 lines from magento_root/var/log/Ebizmarts_Mandrill.log on localhost.

Comment: Thanks. Toxabes. I solve the problem Myself.
For localhost the problem is SSL varification, so need to disable the SSL verification From Mandrill (Mage Monkey).

First Go to The Root Folder Of The Magento Project.

The fix for it is adding a new line at lib/Mandrill/Mandrill.php Line 93.

The new line is
 curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

Answer (score -2):

***Finally The Problem is solved.***
**For localhost the problem is SSL varification, so need to disable the SSL verification From Mandrill (Mage Monkey).**

- First Go to The Root Folder Of The Magento Project.
- The fix for it is adding a new line at lib/Mandrill/Mandrill.php Line
- The new line is

  curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

This Will Work 100%.

Comment: you have forgotten to mentioned the line no.